# Dark theme project and others view at Eclipse under Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows

I'm using the default color theme @ Eclipse under Windows 7, but I've got following problem: in my project explorer and  others view looks terrible. I've tried some solutions - changing colors in eclipse, changing some windows colors, but neither works. Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Here are examples how it is displayed:

ps: I cannot install plugins in eclipse in this machine :/

[image]
[image]

Same problem is with the project explorer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using Eclipse Luna - it's very hard to change this specific colors, you need a theme. Just updated the version to Mars and everything is perfect!